# Why is the program not performing segue when logged in?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a login screen and if credentials are correct when the login button is clicked, the segue will be performed. The segue has the right identifier, and the user is logged in because I am passing data through currentUser, and it is getting displayed in the console indicating the user is logged in, but the segue is not being performed. Why? below is my code for logging in.

```
 @IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let username = self.usernameField.text
    let password = self.passwordField.text


    if(username!.utf16.count) < 4 || (password!.utf16.count < 5){

    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Username must be greater then 4 and Password must be greater then 5", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()

    }else{

        self.actInd.startAnimating()

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username!, password: password!, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

            self.actInd.stopAnimating()

            if ((user) != nil) {

                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Logged In", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)

            }else {

                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

            }



        })

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling performSegueWithIdentifier on a background thread. 
Try wrapping it with

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{



 })
```

Comment: I get an error `2015-10-26 12:21:24.909 Musec[63427:654722] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.`

Comment: I figured it out the problem, it had to do with something else.